# how to change timestamp into date in mysql 5.5?

Tags: mysql, casting

send me the right cast query to use on this :

```
SELECT
id,
device_id,
outlet_id,
duration,
current,
voltage,
kw_used,
outlet_total_kwh,
outlet_kwh_demand_15,
outlet_kw_demand_peak,
submeter_real_kw,
submeter_total_kwh,
submeter_kwh_demand_15,
submeter_kw_demand_peak,
peak_voltage,
peak_current,
demand,
inst_demand,
hist_peek_demand,
power_factor,
crest_factor,
frequency,
app_power,
tot_app_energy,
tot_har_dist_vol,
tot_har_dist_curr,
har_x_dist_v,
har_y_dist_v,
har_z_dist_v,
har_x_dist_c,
har_y_dist_c,
har_z_dist_c,
INTERVAL,
CAST (duration AS DATE)
FROM
  epowerg1.dru;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' CAST (duration as DATE) from epowerg1.dru' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `cast` and `(`

```
CAST(duration as DATE) 
    ^---------------------------here
```

Comment: Ah, just realised [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31784508/2) fixed this. You can revert my edit if needed.

Comment: The edit was very helpful, just re-edit the error back in :)

Comment: Suppose there is a space between CAST and left parenthesis. These is the error message its shows.  => "Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'CAST' "

Comment: select * , CAST(duration as DATE) from epowerg1.dru ;  worked !!!! thanks y'al for the valuable reply .

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to date. By using below SQL.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
```

I don't know what is the format of your duration  column.

Thank You.

Comment: Duration ( timestamp )

Answer (score 0):

create table x
(studentname varchar(50),
dt timestamp);

you can use "cast" operator to convert any datatype into another datatype.
answer is below :
select studentname,dt,cast(dt as date) from x;